# How to get Qt-Creator to build using cygwin make?

Tags: build, path, makefile, cygwin, qt-creator

Does anyone know how to configure Qt-Creator to use cygwin's `make` to build a project?  Maybe this is a simple cygwin-mangled Windows path problem, but I can't get Qt-Creator to find/run cygwin's `make`.  My `make` lives in `/usr/bin`, which is actually `c:\cygwin\c\usr\bin` on my system.  Either way, Qt can't seem to find it using all the obvious build settings I can think of.

Thanks---

Comment: Could you post your .pro and the makefile generated by qmake-qt4 please?

Comment: Another question: why are you trying to use Cygwin's make with Qt Creator?  What is the motivation behind that? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks esavard -- I'm really just trying to use Qt Creator as a lightweight IDE and avoid Visual Studio (this particular project does not use the Qt SDK) for reasons that have no sound rationalization - just preference.  For this existing project, Visual Studio would not export to .pro directly (not sure why; selection was grayed out) but I had a perfectly adequate makefile in cygwin, so thought it might be easiest to build with that.  My hope was that this was a simple path problem, and that I could get Creator to point to cygwin's build-chain.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer works for me using Qt Creator 2.0.93 (beta 2.1), YMMV]

I spent some time tracking down a similar problem: using a non-mingw, non-"supported" build chain from Qt.  It appears that Qt Creator uses different environments for build steps based on whether or not you are using a "Make" or "Custom" build step (see the Projects view).  The only way I was able to control the actual make invoked and, more importantly, the path where it was run from was to change from using "make" build steps to a "custom" build step.  Once I did that, the settings of the PATH environment variable (under build environment) were honored and the right make was chosen.

In other words, try doing these steps:

1. Set the path in your build environment for you project to include your cygwin stuff.
2. Create a "custom" build step that calls Cygwin's make with the appropriate options (copied from the old "make" build step).
3. Delete the old "make" build step.

Answer (score 0):

i'm running qtcreator 3.2.1 on windows 8.1.

just enter tools-> option-> build&run-> kits ->add

set sysroot to cygwin folder (e,g: C:\cygwin64) and compiler type to mingw .

(if and when i set gdb to work with that i'll update)