# Qt Creator 2.7.0 compiler error

Tags: windows, qt, compiler-construction, configuration, mingw

Screen-shot from **Tools > Options > Build & Run > Compilers**
[image]

Screen-shot from **Tools > Options > Build & Run > Qt versions**
[image]

Screen-shot from **Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits**
[image]

Installed **Qt creator 2.7.0** on my **Windows 7**.

Build a test Qt GUI Project - made it run, but encountered the following error:

```
:-1: error: Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options.
```

*Installed **MinGW** and tried level best to configure at QT's  Tools > Options > Build & Run > Compilers, but failed.*

*Performed various combinations on PATH variable in Environment, but failed.*

Nothings working! Not finding any solution.

**Does anyone have any resolution for this?**

***P.S.: No default compiler configured on QT creator.***

Comment: See http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23505, http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23013 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048395/how-to-get-qt-creator-to-build-using-cygwin-make

Comment: @user1929959~ Didn't helped much. I'm configuring with MinGW, not Cygwin.

Comment: For MinGW you can also easily found a tutorial about this, like http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MinGW

Comment: Seems you are trying to use MinGW compiler for Qt libraries compiled for MSVC2010.

Comment: @fasked~ Can you tell me where I'm making mistake? & I how this should have been done. _My requirement is only limited to running Qt projects._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice in screenshot that you have Qt libraries compiled for *MSVC2010*, but you are trying to use them with *MinGW* compiler.

[image: Qt Kits]

On [Qt project "downloads" page](http://qt-project.org/downloads) you will see that there are different binary packages for different compilers. For windows there are 4 packages:

- MinGW 4.7.2 32-bit
- MSVC 2010 32-bit
- MSVC 2010 32-bit with OpenGL
- MSVC 2012 64-bit

You **must** choose package that is binary compatible with your compiler (runtime C library).